# .Net Core - How to creating multiple instances of a class with dependency injection

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a specific scenario where I need to create multiple instances of a class that has dependency injection.

```
foreach (var setting in settings)
        {
            var client = new ServiceClient();
            dict.Add(somekey, client);
        }
```

ServiceClient class constructor has implemented DI for other dependent classes. How do I instantiate ServiceClient class?

Comment: This is a really peculiar requirement. Are you sure you need multiple instances of the `ServiceClient` here?

Comment: In addition to DavidG's question, if you determine you DO need multiple instances you could use the Factory pattern and inject the factory into the class: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C#

Comment: @DavidG yes.. need to maintain separate connection instances.

Comment: @Matthew not sure how to implement factory pattern here. number instances could vary..

Comment: Do you mean database connections?

Comment: @DavidG azure service bus , separate queue connections (number of queues could vary based on configuration settings)

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a *IServiceProvider* to get a service with the *GetService* method "via code".

The service to inject should be transient to get a new Instance each time you request a service from the service provider. If the service to be injected has a scoped lifetime you have to create a new scope around the code to get a new service.

```
var service = serviceProvider.GetService<IService>();
```

Consider using a factory method depending on your use case.