# How to create and configure multiple instances of the same class with dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container

How can one create and configure multiple instances of the same class with dependency injection?

I have seen similar questions / tutorials but I am not understanding it yet.

- [Different implementations of the same interface](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-multiple-implementations-interface)
- [Passing values into constructor along with DI](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-registering-implementations-using-delegates)
- [Using IServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503868/net-core-how-to-creating-multiple-instances-of-a-class-with-dependency-inject)

Here is an example:

**Container**

```
public class App()
{
    public IHost Host { get; }

    public App()
    {
        Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.
            CreateDefaultBuilder().
            ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<ITemperatureSensor, AcmeTemperatureSensor>();
                services.AddSingleton<IAcmeMachine, AcmeMachine>();
                services.Configure<TemperatureSensorOptions>(context.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TemperatureSensorOptions)));
            }).
            Build();
    }
}
```

**Acme Machine**

This is where the temperature sensors should be injected.

```
public class AcmeMachine()
{
    public AcmeMachine( Something? )
    {
        // How inject the temperature sensors?
    }
    
    ITemperatureSensor WaterSensor
    ITemperatureSensor AirSensor
}
```

**Temperature Sensors**

```
public interface ITemperatureSensor
{
    string SerialNumber;
    double GetTemperature();
}

public class AcmeTemperatureSensor()
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; }
    
    public AcmeTemperatureSensor(IOptions<TemperatureSensorOptions> options)
    {
        SerialNumber = options.Value.SerialNumber;
    }
    
    public double GetTemperature()
    {
        return 25.0;
    }
}
```

**Settings**

```
appsettings.json
{
    "WaterSensor": {
        "TemperatureSensorOptions": {
            "SerialNumber": "123",
            },
    },
    "AirSensor": {
        "TemperatureSensorOptions": {
            "SerialNumber": "456",
            },
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174989/how-to-register-multiple-implementations-of-the-same-interface-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to change the appsettings to something like :

```json
{
  // ...
  "Sensors": {
    "WaterSensor": {
      "TemperatureSensorOptions": {
        "SerialNumber": "123"
      }
    },
    "AirSensor": {
      "TemperatureSensorOptions": {
        "SerialNumber": "456"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you will be able to read the config as:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<Dictionary<string, Sensor>>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Sensors"));

class Sensor
{
    public TemperatureSensorOptions TemperatureSensorOptions { get; set; }
}

class TemperatureSensorOptions
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

And inject it into some service as `IOptions<Dictionary<string, Sensor>>`.

Or use a dedicated class instead of `Dictionary`:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<Sensors>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("Sensors"));

class Sensors
{
    public Sensor WaterSensor { get; set; }
    public Sensor AirSensor { get; set; }
}
```

Note that if sensor does not have any other settings the `TemperatureSensorOptions` can be flattened/removed to simplify the config.

If you need to construct the `AcmeTemperatureSensor` by injecting there these settings then you will need either construct them manually or follow the factory pattern.

From the comments:

> If one uses manual construction or the factory pattern, is there a good way to get access to the IoC container services?

Personally I would go with factory pattern which can be quite easily be implemented with `Func<>`'s (though it can have some downsides too, like adding factory parameters will become not that easy):

```cs
enpointServices.AddTransient<Func<TemperatureSensorOptions, AcmeTemperatureSensor>>(sp => 
    opts => new AcmeTemperatureSensor(opts, sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<AcmeTemperatureSensor>>()));
```

And then inject the `Func<TemperatureSensorOptions, AcmeTemperatureSensor>` as dependency and call it.

Also usually in such cases I create and register in DI class like `AcmeTemperatureSensorDeps` to encapsulate all the `AcmeTemperatureSensor` dependencies form DI to make it easier to manage them.

Comment: If one uses manual construction or the factory pattern, is there a good way to get access to the IoC container services?  Would you recommend something like this `_logger = Host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Foo>>();`?

Comment: @JasonC Updated the answer a bit, check it out.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. You mention adding a class that encapsulates all the required dependencies makes it easier to manage them. What do you mean by easier to manage? Is it just that the class that uses it only has one argument in the constructor?

Comment: @JasonC _"Is it just that the class that uses it only has one argument in the constructor?"_ - in short - yes, your class has one parameter besides the "factory" ones.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your class constructors to the following:

```
public AcmeMachine(ITemperatureSensor waterSensor, ITemperatureSensor airSensor)
public AcmeTemperatureSensor(TemperatureSensorOptions options)
```

With those signatures you can have the following DI configuration:

```cs
var temp = Configuration.GetSection("WaterSensor").Get<TemperatureSensorOptions>();
var air = Configuration.GetSection("AirSensor").Get<TemperatureSensorOptions>();

services.AddSingleton(sp => new AcmeMachine(
    waterSensor: new AcmeTemperatureSensor(temp),
    airSensor: new AcmeTemperatureSensor(air));
```

Comment: Would this still be a good solution if there were N sensors? Say N = 5, 10, or 100?

Comment: In that case, please update your question and show how you indent to use such list of 100 sensors and how you want to distinguish between them. Ping me after you updated your question and I'll update my answer.